# Path traced by a ladder sliding down a wall

Tags: conic-sections, locus

I was trying to work out what path a ladder traces as it slides down a wall without slipping. There is plenty of info out there about the loci of single points on the ladder, e.g. the midpoint traces a circle, any other point traces an ellipse. However, I am concerned with the locus of the entire ladder.

[image]

The ladder AB, which is at an angle $\theta$ to the ground and is of arbitrary length 5, has a point $n$ units along its length. Considering the point where the wall meets the ground as the origin, using trig we can see that $x = (5-n)cos(\theta)$ and $y = nsin(\theta)$. This is effectively a parametric equation with parameter $\theta$ and restriction $0 < \theta < \pi/2$. Graphing the locus of this curve for values of $n$ from 0 to 5 gives the following (ignore the other 3 quadrants - I wan't sure how to limit the values of the parameter in GeoGebra):

[image]

The circle graphed there for comparison shows the curve isn't quite circular. So, my question is: what is this curve? Can it be described by an equation?

Comment: So it's an ellipse

Comment: @DavidQuinn it looks to be, but can it be proven?

Comment: Yes if you consider the parametric equations of the ellipse

Comment: @DavidQuinn for one single value of n, the locus is an ellipse, but the curve pictured is a combination of the different ellipses for all values of n

Comment: For each $n\neq 2.5$ it's a different ellipse.

Comment: @DavidQuinn I realise that, but my question is about the combination of all those ellipses. Will that combination necessarily be an ellipse?

Comment: I think you are talking about an astroid https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The end of the ladder against the wall traces a vertically downwards path (scraping against the wall) and the end of the ladder resting on the ground traces a horizontally sideways path (scraping along the ground).

Any point in between the two ends would be a combination of vertical & horizontal movements. At no point during the slide of the ladder along the wall, can any part of the ladder rise vertically i.e. I don't see how a circular/closed loop path can occur.